# Clicking on a specific button to show a specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to show a specific item when clicking on a specific button and then hiding the other siblings.

So, what I have is 6 buttons.

Service 1-6

If someone would click on service 1, I would want my `service-display-box` section to appear (I have it set as `display:none` on page load) and then for just the Service 1 content to appear.

The way I have it now, it hides the sibling buttons I have and doesn't show the `service-display-box` or any of the service areas.

I have included a fiddle below.

Service buttons - When you click on Service 1

```
  <div id="service-tabs-container">
    <div class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab1">Service 1</div>
    <div class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab2">Service 2</div>
    <div class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab3">Service 3</div>
    <div class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab4">Service 4</div>
    <div class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab5">Service 5</div>
    <div class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab6">Service 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to show this:

```
 <div class="service-item-box" id="service1">
      <div class="service-item-title">Service 1</div>
    </div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0vrcsrh/2/#&togetherjs=QUmj719C3F)

Comment: In your question, you say `service-display-box` but the example code shows `service-item-box`.  could you explain or fix this?

Comment: The `service-display-box` is the container/wrap for the section. I want for that to be displayed and then the specific `service-item-box` to be displayed as well.

Comment: I suggest making `.service-tabs-container` visible, hide its children, and then leverage the `:target` selector [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) [w3sch](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp) [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to get the number from the id on the service tab you want, then append that to the id of the service item box:

```
$('.service-tab-block').click(function() {
    $('.service-tab-block').css({"background":"purple"});
    $(this).css({"background":"#000", "color":"#FFF"});

    //To get the service display box to show
    var item_number = $(this).attr('id').replace('service_tab', '');
    $('#service-display-box').show();
    $('#service'+item_number).show().siblings().hide();
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/esayoaqg/1/

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the tabs from going away, but it doesn't show the `service-display-box` or the `service-item-box`

Comment: @Becky, Sorry, I missed the service-display-box, but the service-item-box is being shown (because of the ID).  I've updated my code above

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help!